# The Not Equal Tilde in bash

Tags: bash, shell, equals, tilde

Like presented in the title, 
What's the **opposite** of `"=~"` **operator**?
I really googled for that and I fund just the following solution: `[[ ! $str1 =~ $str2 ]]`
Is there any operator that verify the **opposite** of `"=~"` **operator**?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it? Doesn't `! (X =~ Y)` suffice?

Comment: and why I use that if an operator ready exits?

Comment: @Rhymoid I guess `! X > Y` would suffice but it's nicer to write `X < Y`.

Comment: @TomFenech I **really** hope you mean `X <= Y`.

Comment: @Rhymoid no, I meant `! X >= Y` :)

Comment: @user3629514 Why not using it? Because nobody would understand it. Most languages use and, or, not. That's all you need and many programmers don't even understand xor or bit shifts. My guess for your initial answer would be: use test, it has so many options, nobody knows them all.

Comment: @user2799037 this is the problem, I'm not the only one who use my code, and I've to maximize the optimization ...

Comment: @user3629514: for regular expressions, having a dedicated non-match-operator doesn't optimize anything.

Comment: CShell has the `!~` operator for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no opposing operator in bash up to version 4.3 (current at the time of this post).

`[[ ! str1 =~ str2 ]]` is the way to go.

For such questions, you should use `man` instead of your favourite search engine. The man page of the tool involved -- bash, in this case -- is authoritative, the 'web is hearsay (unless, of course, it led you to the man page ;-) ).

Comment: Amen @DevSolar for the comment on man pages!

Answer (score 2):

Answer is There is **no such Operator in bash** Which does **`!~`** as its there in perl, if you do not want to use already known `( [[ ! $str1 =~ $str2 ]] )` for the purpose then you shall have to use `grep` or `perl` . Something like:

```
x="I like negation"
y="like"


if [[ $(perl -ne "!/$y/ && print" <(echo $x)) == "$x" ]]; then 
echo "Contains"
else
echo "Doesn't contain"
```

But I don't find any reason to miss `!~` in bash as `[[ ! $str1 =~ $str2 ]]` solves the purpose pretty well. May be that the reason its not there in bash.

Consider the first comment on this Answer from DevSolar, It holds when you will go with `grep` or `perl`, which again makes `[[ ! $str1 =~ $str2 ]]` the best out of available.

Comment: Hm... calling an external process is hardly an improvement, neither performance- nor readability-wise.